# javascript regexp toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, toggle

Could someone explain what this means:
    /expanded/.test(classes)

I know the '/' begin and end a regexp and that expanded is the name of a class.  But the .test(classes) does not make sense.

in this function:
    var originalNavClasses;

```
function toggleNav() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('navigation_list');
    var classes = elem.className;
    if (originalNavClasses === undefined) {
        originalNavClasses = classes;
    }
    elem.className = /expanded/.test(classes) ? originalNavClasses : originalNavClasses + ' expanded';
}
```

from:
http://blog.g-design.net/post/42617934013/create-an-accessible-toggle-menu-for-mobile#notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding

```
/expanded/.test(classes)
```

Here, `/expanded/` is a regex object declared with a literal notation. `/.../` are known as regex delimiters, after the second `/` you can use regex modifiers (like `i` - ignore case, `g` - global, `m` - multiline). `classes` is a variable. `test()` just returns true if `classes` contains "expanded" substring, otherwise, it returns false.

See [`RegExp` reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more details.

In this concrete example, the function checks if `classes` contains "expanded" and if yes, use `originalNavClasses`, if not, use `originalNavClasses` + "expanded".